# Options won't print

Tags: python, printing, if-statement

```
while True:

    x = raw_input()
    if x =="personal information": 
         print' Edward , Height: 5,10 , EYES: brown , STATE: IL TOWN:  , SS:'
    elif x =="journal":
       print'would you like  you open a journal or create a new one? open or create'
if x =='createfile':
           name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of the file: ")
           completeName = "C:\\python\\" + name_of_file + ".txt"
           file1 = open(completeName , "w")
           toFile = raw_input("Write what you want into the field")
           file1.write(toFile)
           file1.close()
elif x =='openfile':
       print'what file would you like to open'
       y = raw_input()
       read = open(y , 'r')
       name = read.readline()
       print (name)
```

options wont print there is no output except for personal information. i re pasted the code

Comment: You need to fix your code formatting.

Comment: like the indentations? i have a hard time with that can you help me out with the formatting?

Comment: I would be happy to help. But first, I'm going to ask you to enter your code without any special formatting. This way, I'll know what your actual code is. Just copy-paste the code you have and I'll take it from there

Comment: does `close` block until the file is fully flushed and closed?

Comment: I would think so, though I don't know for sure

Comment: The only actual error here (as shown) is the last line not being indented. Of course, everything outside the while loop will never execute, since it comes after an infinite loop that can't be escaped.

Comment: what do you mean without special formatting? sorry im a beginner bear with me

Comment: Highlight the code in your editor. Hit ctrl-C. click in the question box. Hit ctrl-v. Don't do anything else. (in general, don't do that, but we can't tell if the problem is how you're formatted the code for SO or in your actual code)

Comment: it wont let me put in all that code in the comment box thanks for bearing with me

Comment: the format you see should be the format im using

Comment: @EdwardLaPiere: That can't possibly be right. You never break out of the `while`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: that would explain the output, except that as written it will crash with a SyntaxError immediately.

Comment: i re pasted the code how it exactly was

Comment: do i need to put a break at the end of my code?